# ¿como hago una función que se escriba el valor del QR en formulario y lo envíe?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, ng-cordova

Hola soy nuevo programando, en este momento tengo este problema en *ionic v1*.

El siguiente formulario funciona de manera manual, se ingresa un código al `input` y `submit` llama un controlador, funciona perfecto.

Lo que necesito hacer es habilitar una opción donde se emule este proceso por medio de un *QR*, la función que busco es que se escriba el valor del *QR* en el `input` y de clic en `submit` para que se ejecute el formulario como si lo hiciera manualmente.

```
   <form name="formGift" id="formGift">
      <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
          <input type="text" id="code" name="giftCode" ng-model="giftCode.code" required placeholder="Escribe aqui tu código">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="submitCode(giftCode.code)" id="click">Enviar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Este es el controlador que hice para el lector *QR* y enviar datos al formulario:

```
.controller("lectorController", function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner){
  $scope.leerCodigo = function(){ 
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then (function(imageData){
      alert(imageData.text); // valor del QR
      document.getElementById('code').value = imageData.text; // Ingresa valor al input
      document.getElementById("click").click(); // Click en submit
    });
  },
  function(error){
    alert("ha ocurrido un error : " + error)
  };
});
```

El problema es que, a pesar de que el valor llega al `input`, no hace el `submit`... además de eso, le doy manualmente al botón enviar (`submit`) y el formulario me dice que valor invalido `"empty"`.

Este es el controlador del formulario:

```
.controller('GiftCtrl', function($scope, $state, Gifts, $ionicPopup) {
  $scope.giftCode = {};
  $scope.flagCode = false;
  $scope.submitCode = function(codeBag, user_id){
    var user_id = localStorage.getItem("userId");

    Gifts.getGifts(codeBag,user_id).then(function(Gifts){
      console.log(Gifts);

      if (Gifts.errors) {
        $scope.flagCode = false;
        $scope.giftCode = false;

        if (Gifts.errors === "empty") {
          var title = '¡Código Invalido!';
          var subtitle = 'Verifica que esté bien escrito o solicita uno nuevo';
        } else {
          var title = '¡Este código ya fue usado!';
          var subtitle = 'Verifica que esté bien escrito o solicita uno nuevo';
        }

        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: title,
          template: subtitle,
          type: 'button-positive',
          //cssClass:'energized',
          buttons: [{
            text: 'OK',
            type: 'button-positive',
          }] 
        });

        alertPopup.then(function(res) {
          console.log("Codigo Invalido")
        });
      } else {
        $scope.gifts = Gifts;
        $scope.flagCode = true; 
        //$state.go('tab.gift-detail');
      }
      // console.log($scope.gifts);
    });
  }
})
```

Tal vez sea algo muy simple, pero no lo logro.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61267/discussion-on-question-by-cesar-reyes-como-hago-una-funcion-que-se-escriba-el-v).

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré poner el valor en el `input`. sin embargo no logro hacer que el controlador de click en `submit`.

Este es el controlador

```
.controller("lectorController", function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, servicio){
    $scope.leerCodigo = function(){
            $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then (function(imageData){
                servicio.envia(imageData.text);
            });
        },
    function(error){
        alert("ha ocurrido un error : " + error)
    };
})

.factory('servicio',function($rootScope){
    var service = this;
    service.valor = 'no-cambia';
        service.envia = function(data){
            service.valor = data;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('cambia-valor');
        }
    return service;
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state, servicio,){
    //$scope.giftCode.code = 'World';
    $scope.$on('cambia-valor',function(){
        $scope.giftCode.code = servicio.valor;  
        $state.go('tab.gift');
        // AQUI FUNCIÓN QUE DEBE DAR CLICK EN SUBMIT
    })
});
```

Este el formulario:

```
<form  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="giftCode" ng-model="giftCode.code" required placeholder="Escribe aqui tu código">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="submitCode(giftCode.code)" >Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>    
</div>
```

Lo he intentado con varias formas con ID pero no me da.